# Where to put this Nodejs package

Tags: node.js

I just started on nodejs and downloaded the LTS binary from

https://nodejs.org/en/

However, I can run the executable in the bin folder by `./node` I don't know where to put all these files to let them function as a normal apt-get package. There are sitting in my download folder for now.

The sudo apt-get install nodejs   gives me a older version of node like  v 4.2.6

I did search official installation guide and all that. All it says is download the LTS binary.

```
bobby@bobby-Lenovo-Y430P:~/Downloads/node-v6.9.4-linux-x64/lib$ cd ..
bin  CHANGELOG.md  include  lib  LICENSE  npm-debug.log  README.md  share
```

Comment: Just a though use NVM rather. That would also make it simpler to maintain different versions of nodejs

Comment: @georoot worked. I was mixing the concept of npm and nvm. Thx

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many options where to put them. It's easiest to put it in `/usr/local` because `/usr/local/bin` is likely in your PATH. But there are other options.

For more info see [my tutorial](https://gist.github.com/rsp/edf756a05b10f25ee305cc98a161876a).